# Handling multiple ERC721 Tokens in the same Contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, tokenize, solidity

Is it possible for the same contract to handle multiple `ERC721` tokens? And if so, how?

Let’s say you’re making a game and you need to track two types of `ERC721` tokens: unique **Weapons** and unique **Vehicles**.

You could have Structs for them, as follows:

```
struct Weapon { 
    uint256 IDNumber;
    string type; // Sword, Bow&Arrow, Gun, Rifle, etc.  
    string specialFeature; 
}


struct Vehicle { 
    uint256 IDNumber;
    string type;  // Car, Airplane, Boat, Spaceship, etc.  
    uint256 damageFactor; 
}
```

To track their ownership, you could double the arrays managing them - for example instead of having the standard:

```
// Enumerable mapping from token ids to their owners
EnumerableMap.UintToAddressMap private _tokenOwners;
```

You would do:

```
// Enumerable mapping from token ids to their owners
EnumerableMap.UintToAddressMap private _weaponTokenOwners;
EnumerableMap.UintToAddressMap private _vehicleTtokenOwners;
```

(This may not be the most elegant way, but it's a start.)

The real question though is: how would you handle mandatory functions that are part of the  `ERC721` standard, such as `balanceOf()` and `ownerOf()`?

To be specific, are you allowed to say add an additional argument to these methods’ signatures to help indicate which particular Token you’re querying about?

For example, instead of this:

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view override returns (uint256) {

}
```

You’d add a `tokenName` argument to the function’s signature,  as follows:

```
function balanceOf(address owner, string tokenName) public view override returns (uint256) {
    if(tokenName == “weapon”) {
       return ownerAndHisWeaponTokensDictionary[owner].length;
    }
    else if(tokenName == “vehicle”) {
       return ownerAndHisVehicleTokensDictionary[owner].length;
    }
}
```

And you’d do something similar for `ownerOf()`?

Is this allowable?
And is this even the right approach tackling this - or is there a different way to reason about all of this and approach it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to define 3 separate contracts on 3 separate addresses:

- address `0x123123` as the Weapons ERC-721 token contract
- address `0x456456` as the Vehicles ERC-721 token contract
- address `0x789789` as the actual game contract

In the game contract, you can then call the NFTs contracts to get or validate values:

```
function attack(uint attackerWeaponId) {
    require(weaponsContract.isOwnerOf(msg.sender, attackerWeaponId));
    // ...
}
```

*The `isOwnerOf()` function takes 2 arguments, `address owner` and `uint256 weaponId`. Also, a user can probably own more weapons so that's why I'm showing the validation.*

And the weapons contract `balanceOf(address)` would reflect the total amount of the Weapon NFTs that the user has.

```
mapping (address => Weapon[]) userOwnedWeapons;

function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256) {
    return userOwnedWeapons[msg.sender].length;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I thought about this option of splitting everything into different contracts, but it seemed like it might be a headache. Or that it could get out of hand quickly and you would end up with a dozen contracts - even more, in no time... So are you familiar with contracts/projects that take this approach? Can you give examples? I'd love to look up their code on `Etherscan`.

Comment: By the way, are you confirming that we are indeed NOT ALLOWED to change the signatures of methods such as `ownerOf()` and `balanceOf()` by adding additional arguments to them, as I suggested in my original question?

Comment: You could technically change the method signatures, but then they would not follow the ERC-721 standard (and that's probably what you mean by the "not allowed"). So I strongly discourage that... I'm not that familiar with the NFTs practical examples that much, so I don't know any examples, but I'm sure if you DYOR, you'll find examples. My answer is based on observing and writing implementations of ERC-20, where you also don't see many contracts defining 2+ tokens (even for the practical reasons that Etherscan and other blockchain explorers would not recognize 2+ tokens in the same contract).

Comment: OK got it. Makes sense. And yes, when I said "not allowed" I did mean that you certainly _could_ change method signatures if you wanted to - but then you'd no longer be conformant to the ERC721 standards.  I will continue researching this - and hopefully others will chime in with their advice as it could be useful to others. Thanks again!

Comment: In terms of your suggestion to put each ERC721 in its own separate externally deployed contract, and then have the `GameContract` refer to those contracts, what if you wanted to add another element to your game? So you already have `Weapons` and `Vehicles`, and now you want to add `Potions` for example. Is there a way to design your `GameContract` so that it's able to accept new elements/ERC721 contracts and Tokens so you can keep growing it?

Comment: You can use updgradeable proxy. The contract that users will interact with is the proxy, and then it delegates calls to the actual game contract (v1 - has `Weapons` and `Vehicles`). When you release a new version of the game (v2 - has `Weapons`, `Vehicles` and `Potions`), you set the proxy implementation address to this new game address... OpenZeppelin has a good explanation of upgradable proxies basics: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies